# Android Kotlin Enum Class

Tags: android, kotlin, enums

I'm developing an app which having level and each level will have different symbol and background color. For example, level 1 will have R.drawable.circle, R.drawable.red_background.
Is it possible to store in enum with range like

```
enum class LevelEnum(levelSymbol: Int, levelColor: Int) {
    1..21(R.drawable.circle, R.drawable.red_background),
    22..50(R.drawable.rectangle, R.drawable.blue_background),
    ....
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you specifically ask for an enum class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such case you can use function with `when` and return the `drawble` when your `levelSymbol` is in your desired range.

```
fun levelSymbol(levelSymbol: Int): Int {
        return when (levelSymbol) {
            in 1..21 -> R.drawable.circle
            in 22..50 -> R.drawable.rectangle
            else -> R.drawable.circle
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, much appreciate